# cakephp : How to formulate conditions for left join

Tags: cakephp, join, outer-join

I have two entities: clefs and lots with a n-n association. So I define three models: Clefs, lots and ClefLots:

```
class ClefLots extends AppModel {
    var $specific = true;
    public $name = 'ClefLots';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Clefs' => array(
            'className' => 'Clef',
            'foreignKey' => 'clefs_id'
        ),
        'Lots' => array(
            'className' => 'Lot',
            'foreignKey' => 'lots_id'
        )   
    );
}
```

Now I need to list, for a given clef, which are the lot not associated whith the clef.
This query works:

```
SELECT
    `Lot`.`id`, `Lot`.`title`, `ClefLots`.`clefs_id`, `ClefLots`.`lots_id` 
FROM
    `dunkerque52`.`lots` AS `Lot` 
    LEFT JOIN
        `dunkerque52`.`clef_lots` AS `ClefLots`
            ON (((`ClefLots`.`clefs_id` = '539c1896-1cc0-48ac-a2d6-2c9e5b79c62b')
            AND (`ClefLots`.`lots_id` = Lot.id))) 
WHERE
    `ClefLots`.`lots_id` IS NULL
```

With cakephp this code fails :

```
$this->loadModel('ClefLots');
$conditions = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Lot.id', 'Lot.title', 'ClefLots.clefs_id', 'ClefLots.lots_id'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'clef_lots',
            'alias' => 'ClefLots',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array(
                array(
                    'ClefLots.clefs_id' => $id,
                    'ClefLots.lots_id => Lot.id'
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        "ClefLots.lots_id" => null,
    )
);
$lots = $this->Lot->find('list',$conditions);
```

and that code is incorrect:

```
$this->loadModel('ClefLots');
$conditions = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Lot.id', 'Lot.title', 'ClefLots.clefs_id', 'ClefLots.lots_id'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'clef_lots',
            'alias' => 'ClefLots',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array(
                array(
                    'ClefLots.clefs_id' => $id,
                    'ClefLots.lots_id' => 'Lot.id'
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        "ClefLots.lots_id" => null,
    )
);
$lots = $this->Lot->find('list',$conditions);
```

So my question is: how do I specify the conditions in the left join to get the correct query?

Comment: Did you check a look at the SQL request generated by Cake?

Answer (score 0):

Your `conditions` array is incorrect, it shouldn't contain a nested array, and SQL fragments should be passed as strings.

Also in your SQL fragment there is a `>` after the `=` which shouldn't be there.

This is what the join conditions should look like:

```
'conditions' => array(
    'ClefLots.clefs_id' => $id,
    'ClefLots.lots_id = Lot.id'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not completly clear for me when to specify an sql fragment ('ClefLots.lots_id = Lot.id') and when use the array notation ( 'ClefLots.clefs_id' => $id). But it works great.

Comment: @user3340220 Passing SQL fragments is pretty much the opposite of what is described here: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions** SQL fragments are best used for static expressions only that don't need escaping.